# Parity Chain Spec - Require More GPU RAM?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, asic-resistant

Is there any setting on a Parity chain spec file that would allow the chain to require more than 1GB RAM to start?  or to change the rate of increase per epoch?  This would make a private blockchain more ASIC resistant since by default it will start at 1GB even though on mainnet a 4GB card is a good minimum.